# What does it mean to close an archived slack channel?

Tags: slack

I just got a notification that a slack channel that I was in got archived. If I click it, it shows the following:

> You are viewing channelname, an archived channel

Followed by the button

> Close Channel

What will happen if I or someone else clicks this, will I lose the ability to search the channel history for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are looking at the following:

[image: Close Channel]

then there is no need to worry. **Clicking the Close Channel button does not actually change the state of the channel.**

It will simply bring you back to the channel you were browsing before, afterwards the channel will still be there in the archived state and others will not even notice you have looked at it and closed the screen.

It is also not related to the act of Deleting a channel (which would prevent you from searching the channels contents afterwards).